# Spin wave theory for 1D spin systems

Tags: condensed-matter

In general, when one performs spin-wave theory, he has to assume some kind of long-range ordered state and perform spin-wave theory (using for instance Holstein-Primakoff bosons) around that state. Recall that in 1D there is no long-range order. Then it seems that spin-wave theory in 1D would be meaningless. **But yet, people still do spin-wave in 1D... why ?** (you can just type "spin-wave for spin chain" on google and you'll see plenty of examples)

Comment: As far as I understand, people use the 1D case for simplicity. As for its validity, one can use spin waves or magnons to look at low temperature excitations. Given that at $T=0$ one always has an ordered state, classically, for small $T$, one can use spin wave excitations to calculate, say, their contribution to specific heat etc.